# programming devices in android

Tags: android, mobile, tablet

I wanted to know that if all the devices that support Android OS can be manually reprogrammed or do they allow to make own apps and load in them , just in case I want to program an app for myself or it's restricted to specific devices. How shall I know ?

Update: For example I want to program a personal app to prepare notes in handwritten mode using a stylus and integrate other mathematical instruments in it.Expecting features like adding space in case I want to add notes somewhere at later point of time or completely erase some specific portion of page.

Answer (score 0):

No. The Android SDK allows any Android device to be used an development platform. Unless the manufacturer has explictly disabled this feature. (You can always manually re-enable it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own customized apps and can load them in your android phone, but your android phone's api level should be higher than the app's api level.